# Highcharts chart not updating with new data

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

**Problem description:**

I am using the Highcharts library to create a chart. I want to update the chart data every second, but the chart is not updating. The console doesn't show me any error. The chart is ok to be manually redraw.

Code:

```
    function updateChart() 
        {
            if (chart1 == undefined) {// I used to redraw the whole chart each time I update my data and it works fine
                chart1 = Highcharts.chart('hccont', {
                    chart:
                    {
                        type: 'column',
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,         
                            alpha: 5,               
                            beta: 5,                
                            depth: 55,
                        },
                        events: {
                            load: function () {
//the update() is called in debug each second but it doesn't actually do anything to my chart. no error shown in console.
                                setInterval(function () {
                                    chart1.update({
                                        series: [{
                                            data: count,
                                            name: 'Picked',
                                            showInLegend: false
                                        }],
                                        xAxis: {
                                            categories: studentsName,
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'Names'
                                            },
                                            labels: {
                                                skew3d: true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Statistic'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Let\'s see who are picked the most.'
                    },
                    colors: generateColorArray("#31c1ff", "#ffa4ff", "#ff6464")
                    ,
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: studentsName,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Names'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            skew3d: true
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            margin: 20,
                            text: 'Picked'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            skew3d: true
                        }
                    },
                    credits: { enabled: false },
                    navigation: {
                        buttonOptions: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x} is Picked: {point.y} time(s)</b><br>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            depth: 25,
                            colorByPoint: true
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: count,
                        name: 'Picked',
                        showInLegend: false
                    }]
                });
            }
            
        }
```

The var 'count','studentsName' are properly updated arrays. If I manually redraw the whole chart it works fine. But I don't like the animation of redraw.

**Additional information:**

I am using Highcharts v11.2.0.
I am using the Edge browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setData](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series) to update series and for updating the title and other information update works as usual

```
events: {
    load: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            chart.series[0].setData({
                data: count,
                name: 'Picked',
                showInLegend: false
            });

            chart.update({
                xAxis: {
                    categories: studentsName,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Names'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        skew3d: true
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you for your answering but sadly it still doesn't solve my prob:( I tried multiple ways to get the chart object and use the method you provide to edit the chart but the chart always goes to blank. no xaxis-label, no data column. i double checked my 'count' and 'studentsName' and they are all fine.

I guess this is a bug from highcharts???

Comment: hi! I found a solution eventually! yay. 
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData(
     count
    );